# Calculating Bearing/Direction via Spatial Join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, bearing

I was just wondering if it was possible to calculate a bearing field via a spatial join?

Basically I have needed in the past to calculate distances from one singular point (e.g a well) to a number of different closest attributes for different shapefiles (such as environmental sensitivities, so SPAs, SACs, Pipelines etc, therefore ranging all different vector formats.)

I found out you could do this simply by using a spatial join so I created a model using model builder that basically created spatial joins of my input point to every single environmental variable (selecting the CLOSEST parameter), and after merging all the ouput feature classes gives me an output feature classes with the distances of every closest sensitivity.

However, I also need the bearing from the input point to each environmental variable, however I cannot figure out if this is even possible using the current method I'm using, even though it seems like it should be an easy enough variable to include...

I have tried using "Add Field" and "Calculate Field" after the spatial joining but this does not seem to work, so I wonder if there is somehow a way to do it *during* the spatial joins?

Or any other way?

Comment: What would the "bearing" be from a point to any non-point (that is, extended) feature? If you were to use something like the "Near" tool, you could obtain *a* bearing from the point to (some) nearest point in the feature, but it's not hard to conceive of situations where that bearing would be a deceptive indicator of the actual spatial relationship between the two features. That is why I wonder what the bearing you seek is intended to represent.  If you could expand on that a little in your question, it might suggest alternative solutions. (+1 for an interesting question regardless.)

Answer (score 1):

the easy way is to use the [near](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000) tool, but you need an ArcInfo licence.

otherwise, you could try to create a buffer of the size equivalent to the distance, intersect the buffer with other features, and use the point coordinates to compute the bearing.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the NEar tool, otherwise that would be ideal! Haha! Will try the buffer idea though.

Answer (score 1):

One ModelBuilder option without info license may be to...

In ModelBuilder could you create a distance raster using *Euclidean Distance* and check the box for creating a Euclidean Direction raster (limit the extent by the extent of the merged features) and then just use *Extract Multi Value to Points Tool*"\ to bring the distance and direction values into the point file.